# How to get a google basemap in a python code for QGIS?

Tags: python, google-maps, qgis

I'm creating a python plugin for different users that has the layers that each person need to use and work with in QGIS.

I have no trouble adding rasters from Geoserver using the following code:

```
        wmsTicketDSM= QgsRasterLayer('contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:27700&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=Ticket_DSM&password=XXXXXXXXXXXX&styles=&url=http://63.12.21.231:8080/geoserver/exchange_maps/wms&username=admin', 'Ticket_DSM', 'wms')
        if not wmsTicketDSM.isValid():
            print "Layer wmsTicketDSM failed to load!"
        else:
            print "Raster Layer wmsTicketDSM loaded!"
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(wmsTicketDSM,False)
```

Now I need to add basemaps. How to add a Google Satellite map on python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps can be used as basemaps in Qgis loading them as TMS (Tiled Map Service). From QGIS 2.18 The native support To TMS has been added to Qgis by [Lutra](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2016/10/26/qgis-xyz-tile-wmts-preview/).

```
import requests
service_url = "https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
service_uri = "type=xyz&zmin=0&zmax=21&url="+requests.utils.quote(service_url)
tms_layer = core.QgsRasterLayer(service_uri, "Google Hybrid", "wms")
```

where `lyrs=y` stay for hybrid map, `lyrs=s` for sat map and `lyrs=m` for road map.

Note that the url parameter of the uri has to be percent codes encoded

QGIS previous releases could be supported making use of [TileLayerPlugin](https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin) by [Minoru Akagi](https://github.com/minorua) that exposes the needed methods:

```
plugin = qgis.utils.plugins.get("TileLayerPlugin")
if plugin:
  from TileLayerPlugin.tiles import BoundingBox, TileLayerDefinition
  bbox = None    # BoundingBox(-180, -85.05, 180, 85.05)
  layerdef = TileLayerDefinition(u"title",
                                 u"attribution",
                                 "http://example.com/xyz/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                                 zmin=1,
                                 zmax=18,
                                 bbox=bbox)
  plugin.addTileLayer(layerdef)
else:
  from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox
  QMessageBox.warning(None,
                      u"TileLayerPlugin not installed",
                      u"Please install it and try again.")
```

For Google basemaps replace the proper "attribution" row and the url row with the following:

```
"https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
```

Comment: I tried using the lines directly on qgis and got the following message "Access to the service is restricted by the TOS. Please follow the TOS" ???

Comment: TOS = Terms of Service

Comment: Yes I know but is there a way to automatically skip the message?